# normalising constant on exponential of exponential

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, exponential-family

I have a distribution of the form $\exp(-\exp(-x^2))$. Is this a known family of distributions. Otherwise how would you find/approximate the normalising constant. The domain is $x \in (-\infty,\infty) $

Note: I want to do this without sampling.

Comment: Presumably this is the PDF, because if it were used as a CDF your question would be trivially easy.  However, you need to tell us its domain, because its integral diverges.

Comment: Added the domain. But not sure how it would diverge considering that $\exp(-\exp(-x^2))<\exp(-x^2)$

Comment: The inequality you assert is false. Take $x=1$. $\exp(-x^2)\approx 0.368 < \exp(-0.368)\approx 0.692$. As $|x|$ gets larger, so does your function. Try drawing a picture.